# Crypto++ in Eclipse Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, crypto++

I'm trying to use Crypto++ for my Eclipse C++ project using the MinGW toolchain. Problem is, whenever I try to use crypto functions, I get flooded with "undefined reference" errors. Has anyone experienced this before? This is the what I'm getting (truncated):

UPDATED

```
g++ -L "C:\\Libraries\\crypto++\\Win32\\DLL_Output\\Debug" -lpthread -lcryptopp -o "Grum Net.exe" "src\\Vault\\VaultNode.o" "src\\User.o" "src\\Grum Net.o" 
src\Grum Net.o: In function `ZN8CryptoPP18HashTransformationD2Ev':
C:/Libraries/crypto++/cryptlib.h:531: undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::HashTransformation'
src\Grum Net.o: In function `ZN8CryptoPP18HashTransformationC2Ev':
C:/Libraries/crypto++/cryptlib.h:531: undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Algorithm::Algorithm(bool)'
C:/Libraries/crypto++/cryptlib.h:531: undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::HashTransformation'
src\Grum Net.o: In function `ZN8CryptoPP31IteratedHashWithStaticTransformIjNS_10EnumToTypeINS_9ByteOrderELi0EEELj64ELj16ENS_5Weak13MD5ELj0ELb0EE4InitEv':
C:/Libraries/crypto++/iterhash.h:90: undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5::InitState(unsigned int*)'
src\Grum Net.o:Grum Net.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E[__ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E]+0x18): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int, CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
src\Grum Net.o:Grum Net.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E[__ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E]+0x1c): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int, CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned int&)'
src\Grum Net.o:Grum Net.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E[__ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E]+0x24): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int, CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart()'
src\Grum Net.o:Grum Net.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E[__ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E]+0x44): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int, CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char*, unsigned int)'
src\Grum Net.o:Grum Net.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E[__ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E]+0x4c): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::HashTransformation::TruncatedVerify(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `-L` is inside of your quotes. Have you tried:

```
g++ -L "C:\\Libraries\\crypto++" -lpthread -o "Grum Net.exe" "src\\VaultNode.o" "src\\User.o" "src\\Grum Net.o"
```

Now that g++ know where to look for your libs, you'll also need to specify which libs from the *C:\Libraries\crypto++* directory you'd like to use:

```
g++ -L "C:\\Libraries\\crypto++" -lcryptolib1 -lcryptolib2 -lpthread -o "Grum Net.exe" "src\\VaultNode.o" "src\\User.o" "src\\Grum Net.o"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Eclipse must have been doing something funny...I added a space before the " in the config, and now the statement comes out correctly. However, The undefined reference errors still persist

Comment: Are you also including the specific libraries you need?  When you use -L it will tell g++ _where_ to look for libraries but _not which ones to use_. you also need to -l each one from _C:\\Libraries\\crypto++_ that you want to use.

Comment: My statement is now:
    g++ -L "C:\\Libraries\\crypto++\\Win32\\DLL_Output\\Debug" -lpthread -lcryptopp -o "Grum Net.exe" "src\\Vault\\VaultNode.o" "src\\User.o" "src\\Grum Net.o" 

But the issue is persisting

Comment: Can you update the question with the new statement and resulting error dialogue?